# IOS trigger location permission popup

Tags: ios, swift, cordova

I have implemented geo location functionality in my application.
App first release, We have got permission "access location while using"
But we need to ask again permission popup to change the location permission to Always

Is possible in we provide the update version of app???
Otherwise if permission popup show only once.

Comment: Yes you can request for Always authorization again if not already selected by the user.

Comment: @PGDev   
i have called both "requestWhenInUseAuthorization" and "requestAlwaysAuthorization" in my first version of app but i see only "requestWhenInUseAuthorization" popup.is possible to do it again???

Comment: Do you want requestWhenInUseAuthorization and requestAlwaysAuthorization to pop again?

Comment: i need show requestAlwaysAuthorization popup again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** app's Info.plist must contain both NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys with string values explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Now just replace your line of code

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

with this

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

It will again ask for permission as shown below...

[image]

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: As I tested I used "requestAlwaysAuthorization" and got popup first time. when I changed my method "requestWhenInUseAuthorization" to "requestAlwaysAuthorization" and set my info.plist according to that,  particular location popup was triggered again.

Comment: Ya it is working fine. But i ti s coming only once is correcr??

Comment: @VenkaTeshuser5397700 : yeah it will come at least once. I guess your problem is resolved.

Comment: is poosible to trigger the "requestAlwaysAuthorization" again

Comment: i have called both "requestWhenInUseAuthorization" and "requestAlwaysAuthorization" in my first version of app  but i see only "requestWhenInUseAuthorization" popup.

Comment: I don't think so, it would get called again. I'm not sure though. Try to remove these lines and then run and again write these line and run again.

Comment: My app is in live. downloaded user more than 1000. so we can't update those user ahhh ?